# Solr Jquery AutoComplete Url Source

Tags: java, solr, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, solrj

After browsing thru SO, i found this piece of code everywhere, even I want to implement AutoComplete, I am using Solr to implement search, and wanted to use TermsComponent foe implementing Autocomplet

```
    var cache = {};
    $("#textbox").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
       if (request.term in cache) {
        response($.map(cache[request.term].d, function(item) {
         return { value: item.value, id: item.id }
        }))
        return;
       }
       $.ajax({
        url: "/Services/AutoCompleteService.asmx/GetEmployees",  /* I use a web service */
        data: "{ 'term': '" + request.term + "' }",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
        success: function(data) {
         cache[request.term] = data;
         response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
          return {
           value: item.value,
           id: item.id
          }
         }))
        },
        error: HandleAjaxError  // custom method
       });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function(event, ui) {
       if (ui.item) {
        formatAutoComplete(ui.item);   // custom method
       }
      }
     });
```

Now my question is, How to configure the url source, wat it should be, the following url
    http://localhost:8983/solr/terms?terms.fl=name&terms.prefix=at&wt=json&omitHeader=true
gives me **perfect** result, now pls tell me wat should be my url source, and if i want to customize add more parameters like terms.lower=py&terms.lower.incl=false&indent=true&wt=json etc ,should i better harcode them in url or in my java class like 
    List terms = query(q, Integer.parseInt(limit));

```
private List<TermsResponse.Term> query(String q, int limit) {
List<TermsResponse.Term> items = null;
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.addTermsField("spell");
query.setTerms(true);
query.setTermsLimit(limit);
query.setTermsLower(q);
query.setTermsPrefix(q);
query.setQueryType("/terms");
try {
  QueryResponse qr = server.query(query);
  TermsResponse resp = qr.getTermsResponse();
  items = resp.getTerms("name");
} catch (SolrServerException e) {
  items = null;
}
return items;
```

}

Please help, um not so good in jquery, so wanted to confirm one more thing,for wat i need, i just need to modify the url over here or have to customize few more things

Answer (score 1):

It's not very likely that you need to parameterize this client-side, so set those parameters server-side. Setting them with code instead of hardcoding them in the URL is generally better, it reveals the intention. Also remember that you can [set parameters in the solr config](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration).

Lastly, don't [program by coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence). Understand the jQuery snippet you're using, otherwise you will have problems sooner or later.

Comment: thanks maurico, but can u pls help me out with the url source, i used this..but cant get the resul.. can u tell wats wrong
url:"http://localhost:8983/solr/termsterms.fl=name&wt=json&omitHeader=true&terms.prefix="+this.value